# Can't login with django's test client

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have the following code in my tests.py

```
class TestAdding(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        username = 'testuser'
        password = 'testpass'
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, password=password)
        self.client = Client()
        logged_in = self.client.login(username=username, password=password)
        self.assertTrue(logged_in)
```

I get the following error

```
$ ./manage.py test --settings=quotes.settings_dev
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_add (webapp.tests.TestAdding)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mahmoud/Projects/quotes/webapp/tests.py", line 15, in setUp
    self.assertTrue(logged_in)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.137s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I checked to see whether the user does get created, and it does.

The only problem is logging in.

**Edit**: these parts of my settings file might be relevant.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
```

Comment: do you use custom authentication backend?

Comment: @Marat as a matter of fact, I do. django-guardian and django-allauth both provide custom backends that I use in my app.

Comment: what version of django-allauth do you have installed? Is settings.USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD set?

Comment: @Marat I have version 0.15.0. And no, USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD isn't set.